# Double free error with doubly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

So I'm trying to do a method to clear a doubly linked list for school where the doubly linked list and nodes are defined as:

```
struct word_entry
{
    char *unique_word ;
    int word_count ;
} ;

struct node
{
    struct word_entry one_word ;
    struct node *p_previous ;
    struct node *p_next ;
} ;

struct linked_list
{
    struct node *p_head ;
    struct node *p_tail ;
    struct node *p_current ;
} ;
```

I have a method to clear a linked list by doing

```
int clear_linked_list( struct linked_list *p_list ) //return how many nodes were cleared
{
    if (p_list->p_head == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        int count = 0;
        struct node *curr = p_list->p_head;

        while (curr != NULL) {
            struct node *next = curr->p_next;

            free(curr->one_word.unique_word);
            free(curr);
            curr = next;
            count++;
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```

I do a free() on curr->one_word.unique_word because it's a malloc'd char array. I was taught to free when I use malloc, so that's there.

The issue I run into is I get a "bogus pointer (double free?)" and a core dump when I run the test file provided by my professor. I've worked on this for a few hours and can't seem to find out where (or how) I'm calling free twice.

Comment: Your code as posted doesn't seem to compile, since you access `p_list->p_next`  but `struct linked_list` doesn't have a member `p_next`. Could you double check that the code you posted is the same as the code that produces the error? (If you could add a tiny `main` function to make it a [complete program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that would be great)

Comment: Which language? C or C++. Please decide on one and edit the tags of your question.

Comment: Sorry @DavidZ, I was looking at the wrong thing. Code should be fixed now. The main has about 7k tests so figuring out which test it is / what comes before it is a little difficult.

Comment: Cool, that's better. By the way, no need to include "EDIT:" or comments about your edit in the post itself - that is, your entire last line could be removed, although I don't think it's a big enough deal to make a whole separate edit for just that.

Comment: Are you calling `clear_linked_list` twice with the same list?  When you clear it, you don't reset the `p_head` pointer so it will point at the memory that has already been freed.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I'm not sure, like I said in a previous comment there are some 7k tests. I don't know what's going on around it.

Comment: @DavidZ Sorry! I'm used to reddit

Comment: No worries! Seems like you're doing fine, there are just a few ways in which Stack Exchange differs from reddit that you'll pick up over time, if you haven't already. A couple tips: as mentioned, the revision history of every question and answer is viewable so you don't need to indicate when you edited something in the post itself; also, discussion is kind of discouraged except to the extent needed to make questions and answers as good as they can be. Also you can edit titles here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you loop through the list, you should constantly change the position of the head, so that even if you repeat clear_linked_list, you will not get an error.

```
int clear_linked_list(struct linked_list* p_list)  // return how many nodes were cleared
{
    if (p_list->p_head == NULL) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int count = 0;
        while (p_list->p_head != NULL) {
            struct node* curr = p_list->p_head;
            p_list->p_head = p_list->p_head->p_next;

            free(curr->one_word.unique_word);
            free(curr);
            count++;
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have exactly what you have, and I still get an `in free(): bogus pointer (double free?)` and an arbitrary memory address

Answer (score 0):

When freeing memory it is a good practice to set NULL to pointers that were freed to avoid this kind of problems.
So you should do:

```
free(curr->one_word.unique_word);
curr->one_word.unique_word=NULL; 
//if that one_word.unique_word was shared between multiples nodes that free could cause problems if you dont set it to NULL afterwards
free(curr);
curr=NULL; //or curr=next...
```

Also. Check that when you create the nodes that:

- *p_next is NULL on the last node of the double linked list
- *p_previous  is NULL on the first node of the list

Answer (score 0):

You don't null out `p_head` before you leave the clear function.

So, if you called it twice, you'd have problems (i.e. `p_head` would point to an already freed node). Likewise for `p_tail`.

Also, if you tried to add to the list again, you'd have similar problems.

Otherwise, your clear code is just fine.

So, can you prove that the list is *constructed* correctly (e.g. before you `free`, add a `printf` that prints out all the node's pointers *before* you free anything).